# How to recursively find & replace whole files with bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have hundreds of files that I need to recursively replace as the files are currently stored like so:

```
/2019/01/
file1.pdf
file2.pdf

/2019/02
file3.pdf
file4.pdf

etc
```

I then have all of the updated files in another directory like so:

```
/new-files
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
file3.pdf
file4.pdf
```

Could someone please tell me the best way of doing this with a bash script? I'd basically like to read the new-files directory and then replace any matching file names in the other folders.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are all the filename unique?  There would be no collisions if they were all moved into the same directory?

Comment: All filenames are unique. I want all files in a single directory to replace the matching file in another directory where files are sorted into multiple directories. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 'new-files' directory and all the directory trees containing PDF files are under the current directory, try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

find . -path ./new-files -prune -o -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 \
    |   while IFS= read -r -d '' pdfpath; do
            pdfname=${pdfpath##*/}
            new_pdfpath=new-files/$pdfname
            if [[ -f $new_pdfpath ]]; then
                printf "Replace '%s' with '%s'\n" "$pdfpath" "$new_pdfpath" >&2
                # cp -- "$new_pdfpath" "$pdfpath"
            fi
        done
```

- The `-path ./new-files -prune` in the `find` command stops the 'new-files' directory from being searched.
- The `-o` in the `find` command causes the next test and actions to be tried after checking for 'new-files'.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of the use of the `-print0` option to `find` and the `while IFS= read -r -d '' ...`.  In short, the code can handle arbitrary file paths, including ones with whitespace and newline characters in them.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${pdfpath##*/}`.
- It's not clear to me if you want to copy or move the new file to replace the old file, or do something else.  Run the code as it is to check if it is identifying the correct replacements to be done.  If you are happy with it, uncomment the `cp` line, and modify it to do something different if that is what you want.
- The `--` in the `cp` command protects against arguments beginning with dash characters being interpreted as options. It's unnecessary in this case, but I always use it when arguments begin with variable (or other) expansions so the code will remain safe if it is used in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this calls for a bash array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Make an associative array
declare -A files=()

# Populate array as $files[file.pdf]="/path/to/file.pdf"
for f in 20*/*/*.pdf; do
  files[${f##*/}]="$f"
done

# Step through files and replace
for f in new-files/*.pdf; do
  if [[ ! -e "${files[${f##*/}]}" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: missing $f" >&2
    continue
  fi
  mv -v "$f" "${files[${f##*/}]}"
done
```

Note that associative arrays require bash version 4 or above. If you're using the native bash on a Mac, this won't work as-is.

Note also that if you remove `continue` in the final lines, then the `mv` command will NOT safely move files that do not exist in the date hash directories, since no target is known.

If you wanted further protection you might use `test -nt` or friends to confirm that an update is happening in the right direction.